# Passing data from axios request to react jsx views from express middleware

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am building an application in which I'm doing the server-side rendering for the react-redux app. I need to use dynamic data. I'm using express middleware to make an axios request. I'm unable to pass the response data from express middleware to react view. The middleware is working correctly and the data is displayed on the console. Similarly, the static files of the views are displayed correctly.

How can I pass data from express middleware to react jsx views?

Comment: Can you show us some code? How are you trying to pass these data?

Comment: const fetchData = async (req, res, next) => {
  req.data = await fetch('apiPath')
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(myJson) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(myJson));
    });
  next();
};

Comment: Calling middleware using app.get("/news", fetchData);